# error occurred while parsing EntityName on xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have found that there exists `"&"` in my code that's why error is showing

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(dsExport.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SubmissionData"].ToString());
```

The "&" is there in submissiondata . How can I remove the special characters so that the error doesn't show again ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 14, position 84.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request.                                       Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Xml.XmlException: An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 14, position 84.

Source Error:


Line 45:             {
Line 46:     
Line 47:               xmlDoc.LoadXml(dsExport.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SubmissionData"].ToString());

Comment: i found out that "&" is there is submissiondata. thats why the error is showing

Comment: @pal thingbo the same problem is occuring for me http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08cf7e24-a46d-4d8d-a286-2688c73b6e6b/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace your `"&"` with `"&amp;"`

Comment: but it is taking from the Web service. we are not giving it manually.

Comment: @MicrosoftDJ please expand your answer, it does not sufficiently explain what's wrong and has been automatically marked by the system as a low quality post as a result.

Answer (score 0):

& is not an illegal XML character. This is not your problem. You need to log the XML that you receive, before you ask anyone about your problem. You probably need to

```
HTTPUtility.HTMLDecode(yourformdata)
```

But I smell SQL injection a long way.

Comment: thingbo the same problem is occuring for me http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08cf7e24-a46d-4d8d-a286-2688c73b6e6b/an-error-occurred-while-parsing-entityname

Comment: its showing error  The name 'HTTPUtility' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
string str  = dsExport.Tables[0].Rows[i]["SubmissionData"].ToString();
str = System.Web.HTTPUtility.HTMLDecode(str);
xmlDoc.LoadXml(str);
```

Comment: its showing error The name 'HTTPUtility' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Make sure you have:

    using System.Web;

Comment: You need to show us the XML (or parts of it), or we can't help you. Write the XML to a file, and post it here.

Comment: IT's HttpUtility, isn't it?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I am replying too late but I hope it will help some other guys. This issue is because of the encoding of special characters in XML. Please find the below link which may help you https://support.google.com/checkout/sell/answer/70649?hl=en
Thanks,
Vijay Sherekar